# Short proof for the determinant of a $4$ by $4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, proof-writing, determinant, alternative-proof

> Prove that $\det \begin{bmatrix}x&y&z&t\\-y&x&-t&z\\-z&t&x&-y\\-t&-z&y&x\end{bmatrix} = (x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2)^2$

I'm looking for an elegant proof that doesn't involve bruteforce.

Since the answer is given, I'm thinking we can argue that the determinant here is a homogeneous polynomial $P(x,y,z,t)$ with degree $4$, that is invariant under $x\to -x$ and permutations of $x,y,z,t$.

As a result, $P(x,y,z,t) = \lambda (x^4+y^4+z^4+t^4) + \delta (x^2y^2+x^2z^2 + x^2t^2+y^2z^2 + y^2t^2 + z^2t^2)$

$\lambda$ and $\delta$ can be found by computing $P(0,0,0,1)$ or some such.

> The problem is, it doesn't look easy to prove that $P$ doesn't change under permutation of $x,y,z,t$, neither that it's invariant when the variables are negated.

Can you suggest another short proof, or prove the two claims above ?

Comment: The matrix is the sum of $xI$ and an anti-symmetric matrix $A$; i.e., $A$ equals the negative of its transpose.  I wonder if that can't be used to compute
$$
\det(x I + A).
$$

Comment: This question can probably be reframed in terms of the real matrix representations of the quaternions (shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations).) It presumably reflects that $|x+i y+zj+t k|^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio still, you gotta compute this pfaffian

Comment: If you limit yourself to the case of $x=0$, then the formula for the Pfaffian of a generic 4-by-4 skew-symmetric matrix (found in @JackD'Aurizio's link) immediately gives the determinant as $(y^2+z^2+t^2)^2$. (I imagine there's some simple way to restore the $x$-dependence.) Of course, there's' still the matter of how one obtains said formula in the first place...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
   x &  y &  z &  t \\
  -y &  x & -t &  z \\
  -z &  t &  x & -y \\
  -t & -z &  y &  x
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   x & -y & -z & -t \\
   y &  x &  t & -z \\
   z & -t &  x &  y \\
   t &  z & -y &  x
\end{pmatrix} = (x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2)
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Comment: what's the rationale behind this ? Did you find it by luck while scrapping things ?

Comment: $$x+y i \sim \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ -y & x \end{pmatrix}$$ Now $$\det  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -\bar{b} & \bar{a} \end{pmatrix}= a\bar{a}+b\bar{b}$$ $$x+yi=a$$ $$z+ti=b$$

Comment: That's similar to the logic I had (see my answer). The impetus in my case was that it reminded me of $|x+i y|^2+|z+i t|^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2$.

Comment: The same trick can be applied to any antisymmetric matrix $A$.  In particular:
$$
(xI + A)(xI + A)^T = (xI + A)(xI - A) = x^2I - A^2
$$
In this case, $A^2$ is a multiple of the identity.

Answer (score 12):

The matrix has the two-by-two block form $$M=\begin{pmatrix} xI+yJ & zI+t J \\ -zI+t J & xI-yJ \end{pmatrix}$$ where $I$ is the 2-by-2 identity matrix and $J=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0 \end{pmatrix}$. Since these four matrices commute, the determinant of $M$ by treating the elements as scalars and then taking the determinant of the result: \begin{align}\det{M}&=\det[(xI+y J)(xI-yJ)-(-zI+tJ)(-zI-tJ)]\\&=\det[(x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2)I]\\&=(x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2)^2.\end{align}

Comment: See this link for a discussion of the block-determinant result I'm using: http://www.ee.iisc.ac.in/people/faculty/prasantg/downloads/blocks.pdf

Comment: Nice, at least it's not too out of the blue

Comment: In terms of Kronecker products, we have
$$
M = \pmatrix{x&z\\-z&x} \otimes I + \pmatrix{y&z\\-z&-y} \otimes J
$$

Comment: It's also matrix representation of quaternion $q=x+y\mathbf{i}+z\mathbf{j}+t\mathbf{k}$

Comment: @NgChungTak Yep. See my comment to the question itself :). Your answer, then, corresponds to the fact that $|q|^2=q\overline{q}=x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2$.